# dimension OLAP Cube cannot processed

Tags: ssms, ssas, olap-cube

I try to make dimension OLAP Cube, but when I processed the dimension the result is error like this:

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>SSAS_siakad1</DatabaseID>
        <DimensionID>DI Mprovinsi</DimensionID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
    Processing Dimension 'DI Mprovinsi' completed.
        Start time: 4/5/2021 8:28:17 PM; End time: 4/5/2021 8:28:17 PM; Duration: 0:00:00
        Processing Dimension Attribute '(All)' completed.
            Start time: 4/5/2021 8:28:17 PM; End time: 4/5/2021 8:28:17 PM; Duration: 0:00:00
        Processing Dimension Attribute 'NAMA PROVINSI' completed.
            Start time: 4/5/2021 8:28:17 PM; End time: 4/5/2021 8:28:17 PM; Duration: 0:00:00
Errors and Warnings from Response
    Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
    The following system error occurred:  The user name or password is incorrect. 
    Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'DWH Siakad', Name of 'DWH Siakad'.
    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'DI Mprovinsi', Name of 'DI Mprovinsi' was being processed.
    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'NAMA PROVINSI' attribute of the 'DI Mprovinsi' dimension from the 'SSAS_siakad1' database was being processed.
    Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
```

what should I do to resolve that problem? thank you for advance

Comment: Error says: `The following system error occurred:  The user name or password is incorrect. `

Comment: I have checked the server again and it worked, thank you @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the SSAS instance has, in Security properties, registered the user you use to the full-process, also if user has permissions for ProcessFull in SSAS_siakad1 cube. Try to process the dimension manually.

Comment: I do not think that the issue is the user you use to connect to SSAS is the problem (as your answer suggests). I would rather think it has to do with the user connection to the relational data source.